# how can i write image in resources folder in spring mvc project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, bufferedimage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjooQ.png)

```
@GET
    @Path("/welcome1")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response image() {
        try {
            BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("F:\\images\\1.jpg"));
            ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", new File("resources\img\copyright.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }    
        return null;    
    }
```

> I want to load image form my disk to project folder.but i got the
>   error (the system can not find  specific path).
>
> The error is:
>
> > java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\img\copyright.jpg (The
> >     system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: There is no src folder in your Running App

Answer (score 1):

A `File` represents a file in file system, not a file in the classpath. The classpath contains the locations where your classes and resources are. The classes and resources are usually copied somewhere for the runtime of the application, for example into a jar-file or a directory.

Your code makes unusual assumptions considering your classpath and it relies on the current working directory. I recommend to write the file to file system because you don't mention that it is needed that the application modifies itself.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, it would be helpful if you included an example of your directory structure.

In general, a non existent file will be created by Java only if the parent directory exists. You should check/create the directory tree and then the file.

You also need to construct your path.

```
    //User directory - can also use System.getProperty("user.dir")
    String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
    String filename = "abc.txt";
    File f = new File(path + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "org" + File.separator + "project" + File.separator + "playground" + File.separator + filename);
    //You should also check to make sure that the directory exists. I didn't do that here.
    if (f.createNewFile()) {
        System.out.println("File is created!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("File already exists.");
    }
```

Notice how I'm not using `\` or `/` because those depends entire on the system. (Windows/Unix), which by the way if you are using windows, then you are using the wrong brackets in java, so it's just easier to use the built in functionality.